# What age was Sofia in AC Embers?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

In the short movie Ezio plays a old man, maybe in his 70's. Now I understand that all characters in the movie have flawless skin. You can understand that Ezio is old from his hair color. But Sofia, his wife, looks flawless and looks like she is in her 30's? So roughly what age was Sofia in the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sofia's entry in the Animus in *Revelations* indicates that she was born in 1476.  This would make her 17 years younger than Ezio.

More specifically, *Embers* takes place in 1524.  This makes Sofia 48 and Ezio 65 (give or take a few months, of course).